# Hosting Jupyter Notebook Python App on a Webpage

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook

I've made a simple python GUI application using ipywidgets, ipycanvas, and numpy. I made the program on Jupyter notebook as an ipynb file. I would now like to take my application and put it on a webpage. What is the best way to take this Jupyter notebook app and host it on the web?

I've looked a bit into Binder and Django, but I can't seem to find enough resources or documentation on the net to help me learn how to do this.

Comment: Here's an example https://elc.github.io/posts/embed-interactive-notebooks/

Answer (score 1):

If you already have it working as a Jupyter notebook (`.ipynb` file), I'd suggest that sticking with that as the core item for now. I'd suggest getting running via MyBinder.org based on either [this example repo](https://github.com/binder-examples/appmode) or [this one](https://github.com/binder-examples/jupyter-extension). Or a combination of the two.
[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owSGVOov9pQ&feature=youtu.be) is recent and a good reference for many of the steps of setting up a repo with your content.
You essentially make a copy of the Binder templates under your control and then edit them to have your content. You adapt the URLs that trigger launches so that when you share the link, they launch a session via MyBInder.org with your content. Most often the steps can be performed right in the Github browser-based interface without you needing to use git or work locally. If you have something fancier you need, you may have to move to using more complex [configuration file set-ups](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_files.html) and those may necessitate some use of git and local editing.

If you hit some technical road blocks, post your questions [here](http://discourse.jupyter.org/c/questions) using the 'questions' category as suggested in [this post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/debugging-your-binder/33?u=fomightez) about 'Debugging your Binder'.

Maybe once the basics of sharing the notebook or appmode version are working with your own content, you may want to check out [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) or some of the other ways you can share a jupyter notebook-based app discussed [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-transform-a-jupyter-notebook-into-a-webapp/758).

Comment: MyBinder is a great idea. However, in practice it may not work smoothly, most likely due to its popularity. Often it takes very long until it spins up a container -- my students had some bad experience with it. For learning/testing it's good though where you don't need a particularly robust behaviour.

Comment: I should update  this answer to include [Voici](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voici) as well. Voici is JupyterLite and Voila combined. So the computational resources to run it come from the client browser. Hence no remote machine is needed. I'll point out that the MyBinder service relies on donation of compute resources. In April 2023, the largest member of mybinder.org left the group as funding ran out. While obviously not feasible for all, I'll point out that supporting the service would be one way to improve the current conditions.  Other issues have arisen from time to time...

Comment: <continued> since the loss of the largest member and [this post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/too-many-users-on-this-binderhub-try-again-soon/20908/2?u=fomightez) may provide more context for why it can be 'bumpy' at times.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. It's really sad that funding ran out for Mybinder's largest member. I would like to make it clear again that I find Mybinder **great**, my comment was meant as a sort of "expectation management" only. It's a small wonder that such a free service is possible _at all_, no surprise that it cannot give you the sort of high availability a paid service must.

Comment: Sure. I very much appreciate you find it great. I simply wanted to add a fuller account of why at times it can be a bit rocky. Plus, you never know who might be reading.

Answer (score 0):

Jupyter itself is made with Tornado web framework.
There are many bindings to another popular web frameworks.
I once tried on it, and I found that [pyramid-notebook](https://github.com/websauna/pyramid_notebook) is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick build I recommend Binder. This is how you can quickly set up Binder with voila:

Checkout this Git Repo: https://github.com/lschmiddey/book_recommender_voila

In combination with this blogpost: https://lschmiddey.github.io/fastpages_/2020/09/28/Build-binder-app-Part4.html